# Is it currently possible to generate a changelog steam with the Data Generator Source from FLIP-238

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, data-generation, change-data-capture, flink-table-api

In FLIP-238 and the related merge,  new DataGeneratorSource was introduced. It appears that this allows us to easily create new DataGeneration sources. However it's not clear if in it's current form allow users to generate a Changelog DataStream. Then is it possible to generate a Changelog Datastream?

If not perhaps it will be possible when future developments are made to Flink and the DataGeneratorSource.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-238%3A+Introduce+FLIP-27-based+Data+Generator+Source

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-27919